# how to get last revision id created after wp_update_post

Tags: wp-update-post

wordpress always store revision after call wp_update_post.
How to get the post revision ID after call wp_update_post?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wp_get_post_revisions`.

```
<?php
// some logic here

$post_id = wp_update_post(/* ... */);
$latest_revision = array_shift(wp_get_post_revisions($post_id));

if ($latest_revision) {
   // do stuff with the latest revision
   // $latest_revision->ID will contain the latest revision
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `array_shift`, and NOT `array_unshift`. So it would be: $latest_revision = array_shift(wp_get_post_revisions($post_id));

Comment: Good catch, changed!

Comment: Note that `array_shift()` rebuilds the array index. It is rather slow. Since you don't need that array later, you could just use `current()`.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly easier approach if you only need the current revision is to use the function added in WP5.6 wp_get_latest_revision_id_and_total_count() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_latest_revision_id_and_total_count/. It's kind of unfortunate there isn't just a "get_latest_revision_id" function but this one will return it, along with the total count. It's easier than looping over all revisions which we had to do prior.